# Trying to override Drupal core 'find content' with a view and VBO

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to replace the core content admin area with a view and VBO. I managed to create the view and have it override admin/content/node without an issue. However the administer content area is also accessible by admin/content. I tried creating a second view to override it but it breaks the menu. It appears to be a menu router issue. Any thoughts on how to overcome this (other than adding a redirect)?

Answer (score 1):

Views doesn't really know how to override paths. It always breaks menus.
You need the [Admin Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) module that provides some extra code for overriding to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Contextual Administration](http://drupal.org/project/context_admin) module. You can use it to easily recreate the same kind of 'find content' page with VBO and it's pretty flexible.

As for your current approach, I haven't looked into it too much but I'd think a redirect may be your best bet.